# Stripe Java- List Price Filter

Tags: stripe-payments

I have been trying to filter the price records by active, product & lookup_keys.
Here is the snippet of the code:

```
public Price getPrice(String productId, String priceLookupKey) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("lookup_keys", priceLookupKey);
        params.put("product", productId);
        params.put("active", true);
        params.put("limit", 3);
        PriceCollection priceCollection = Price.list(params);
        List<Price> prices = priceCollection.getData();
        if (prices.isEmpty())
            return null;
        return prices.get(0);
    }
```

Getting below error:

```
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: Invalid array; request-id: req_xeP0JR6RoY1Him
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.handleApiError(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:158) ~[stripe-java-20.45.0.jar:20.45.0]
    at com.stripe.net.LiveStripeResponseGetter.request(LiveStripeResponseGetter.java:61) ~[stripe-java-20.45.0.jar:20.45.0]
    at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.request(ApiResource.java:179) ~[stripe-java-20.45.0.jar:20.45.0]
    at com.stripe.net.ApiResource.requestCollection(ApiResource.java:199) ~[stripe-java-20.45.0.jar:20.45.0]
    at com.stripe.model.Price.list(Price.java:175) ~[stripe-java-20.45.0.jar:20.45.0]
    at com.stripe.model.Price.list(Price.java:168) ~[stripe-java-20.45.0.jar:20.45.0]
    at com.iclinica.closefriend.payment.service.StripePaymentService.getPrice(StripePaymentService.java:91) ~[classes/:na]
```

Using only those parameters which are described at https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/list?lang=java#list_prices,   Is this a mistake in the docs, or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try commenting out `lookout_keys` *or* `product`? My experience with their documentation is that sometimes it might be poorly written and confusing. It could be that if you supply one parameter, you cannot supply the other.

I have a feeling that `lookout_keys` and `product` cannot be specified together.

Also, it will be useful if you could look at the Logs in your Stripe dashboard, and search for the request log for request `req_xeP0JR6RoY1Him`. It should give you the full reason.

Comment: You are correct, docs were looking good & clear when I was going through the document, but it seems, it might be not updated, and also thorough examples not included

Comment: Good to know that's the case. :) Do accept my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`lookup_keys` expects you to provide a list of values, eg: `lookup_keys=['SOME_KEY', 'SOME_OTHER_KEY']`

Looks like this is underspecified in the docs, but the error you shared provided sufficient hints for me to test this and confirm the list structure works.